# How to write code for Binary Search Tree Deletion?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have written the following pseudocode for a removeNode() method while working with BST's:

```
If left is null
 Replace n with n.right
Else if n.right is null
 Replace n with n.left
Else
Find Predecessor of n
Copy data from predecessor to n
Recursively delete predecessor*
```

Not only do I want this method to delete or remove Nodes, but I also want it to return true if the deletion is successful.

This is what I have written so far, and I was wondering if anyone would have feedback, suggested changes, or tips to help me complete the method. I will also attach my whole program below this method.

```
   private void removeNode(Node<E> n) {
      if (n.left == null) {
         replace(n, n.right);
      } else if (n.right == null) {
         replace(n, n.left);
      } else {
      //How do I find pred of n
      //Copy data from pred to n
      //Recursively delete pred
      }

   }
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends BinaryTree<E> {

   public boolean contains(E item) {
      return findNode(item, root) != null;
   }

   private Node<E> findNode(E item, Node<E> n) {
      if (n == null || item == null) return null;
      int result = item.compareTo(n.data);
      if (result == 0) {
         return n;
      } else if (result > 0) {
         return findNode(item, n.right);
      } else {
         return findNode(item, n.left);
      }
   }

   public E max() {
      Node<E> m = maxNode(root);
      return (m != null) ? m.data : null;
   }

   private Node<E> maxNode(Node<E> n) {
      if (n == null) return null;
      if (n.right == null) return n;
      return maxNode(n.right);
   }

   public E min() {
      Node<E> m = minNode(root);
      return (m != null) ? m.data : null;
   }

   private Node<E> minNode(Node<E> n) {
      if (n == null) return null;
      if (n.left == null) return n;
      return minNode(n.left);
   }

   public E pred(E item) {
      Node<E> n = findNode(item, root);
      if (n == null) return null;
      Node<E> pred = predNode(n);
      return (pred != null) ? pred.data : null;
   }

   private Node<E> predNode(Node<E> n) {
      assert n != null;
      if (n.left != null) return maxNode(n.left);
      Node<E> p = n.parent;
      while (p != null && p.left == n) {
         n = p;
         p = p.parent;         
      }
      return p;
   }

   public E succ(E item) {
      Node<E> n = findNode(item, root);
      if (n == null) return null;
      Node<E> succ = succNode(n);
      return (succ != null) ? succ.data : null;
   }

   private Node<E> succNode(Node<E> n) {
      assert n != null;
      if (n.right != null) return minNode(n.right);
      Node<E> p = n.parent;
      while (p != null && p.right == n) {
         n = p;
         p = p.parent;         
      }
      return p;
   }

   public void add(E item) {
      if (item == null) return;
      if (root == null) {
         root = new Node<>(item, null);
      } else {
         addNode(item, root);
      }
   }

   private void addNode(E item, Node<E> n) {
      assert item != null && n != null;
      int result = item.compareTo(n.data);
      if (result < 0) {
         if (n.left == null) {
            n.left = new Node<>(item, n);
         } else {
            addNode(item, n.left);
         }
      } else if (result > 0) {
         if (n.right == null) {
            n.right = new Node<>(item, n);
         } else {
            addNode(item, n.right);
         }
      } else {
         return;  // do not add duplicates
      }
   }


   public boolean remove(E item) {
      Node<E> n = findNode(item, root);
      if (n == null) return false;
      removeNode(n);
      return true;
   }

   private void removeNode(Node<E> n) {
      if (n.left == null) {
         replace(n, n.right);
      } else if (n.right == null) {
         replace(n, n.left);
      } else {
      //How do I find pred of n
      //Copy data from pred to n
      //Recursively delete pred
      }

   }

   private void replace(Node<E> n, Node<E> child) {
      assert n != null;
      Node<E> parent = n.parent;
      if (parent == null) {
         root = child;
      } else if (parent.left == n) {
         parent.left = child;
      } else {
         parent.right = child;
      }
      if (child != null) child.parent = parent;
   }


   public String toString() {
      return inorder();
   }
```

Comment: @Coder Great, thanks!

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't sound right to me. You should get the smallest node in the right child tree, break it off and put its value in the node you want to delete. There's a big explanation [here](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Removal) that will help you.

Comment: @Coder You clearly state that Code Review only takes questions about working code, not incomplete code. It's fine to look on Code Review for examples to study, but not to post this question there.

Answer (score 0):

The code to remove an element is very straightforward.

1. Search for the node you want to remove.
2. Check if the node has children.
3. Case 1 - Has Only left child -> Replace current node with left child.
4. Case 2 - Has Only right child -> Replace current node with right child.
5. Case 3 - Has both children -> Find smallest element in right child subtree, replace current node with that node and then delete that node.

The Code can be implemented recursively as follows ->

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.remove = function(data) {
var that = this;
var remove = function(node,data){
   if(node.data === data){
       if(!node.left && !node.right){
           return null;
       }
       if(!node.left){
           return node.right;
       }
       if(!node.right){
           return node.left;
       }
       //2 children
       var temp = that.findMin(node.right);
       node.data = temp;
       node.right = remove(node.right,temp);

    }else if(data < node.data){
        node.left = remove(node.left,data);
        return node;
    }else{
        node.right = remove(node.right,data);
        return node;
    }
  };
 this.root = remove(this.root,data);
};
```